# Post form with only input buttons passing parameters to Action in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Im working on my thesis work, im making a simple browser game, so far I have a form with 3 buttons that I want to invoke the same action with diffirent parameters this is what i've figured so far:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Gather", "Character", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "btn-group-vertical mr-2", @role = "group", }))
{
    <h3>Woods:</h3>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Woods of Deloria (90%)" />
    @Html.Hidden("area", "woods")
    @Html.Hidden("type", "deloria")

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Woods of Forgotten souls (50%)" />
    @Html.Hidden("area", "woods")
    @Html.Hidden("type", "forgotten souls")

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Shadowforest (10%)" />
    @Html.Hidden("area", "woods")
    @Html.Hidden("type", "shadowforest")
}
```

My question is how do i make the diffirent buttons to pass diffirent types, all buttons have to be in same form otherwise it breaks my css. I am using hidden, since I don't want the user to be able to edit the values that are passed as parameters, also I don't want to values to be passed onto the URL.

**EDIT: I realized that @Html.Hidden doesn't hide it from the html, what would my approach be if i want to pass parameters to an action from a button, that the user can't edit?**

**EDIT 2:** Alright so i made some progress, changed the form to

```
<form method="post" class="btn-group-vertical mr-2" role="group">
    <h3>Woods:</h3>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="deloria" value="Woods of Deloria (90%)" />

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="forgotten souls" value="Woods of Forgotten souls (50%)" />

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="shadowforest" value="Shadowforest (10%)" />
</form>
```

And my post action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Gather(int id)
    {
        var taskName = "";

        if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("deloria"))
        {
            taskName = "deloria";
        }
        else if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("forgotten souls"))
        {
            taskName = "forgotten souls";
        }
        else if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("shadowforest"))
        {
            taskName = "shadowforestD";
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(taskName))
        {
            return Json("uh oh");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(taskName);
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's a mess, but i will find a way to make it a little more compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at the various options outlined here:

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/c69d78a3-21d7-416b-9d10-6b812a862778.aspx

If you are using Razor Pages, and not traditional MVC, you should take a look at handler methods:

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods